# Django Foreign Key to Permission

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I would like to add another field for `required_permission` which should be a foreign key to a permission. What should that field definition look like?

The reasoning behind this is that in a template, I can use something like this (psuedo code)

```
{% for app in application_list %}
    {% if user_has_permission(app.required_permission) %}
        Show App
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Function calling like that wont work in template, you have to use template tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your `required_permission` can be a `CharField`. As long as you can create a list of permissions to use with this function.

> **has_perms(perm_list, obj=None)**
>   Returns True if the user has each of the specified permissions, where
>   each perm is in the format `"<app label>.<permission codename>"`. If the
>   user is inactive, this method will always return False.
>
> If obj is passed in, this method won’t check for permissions for the
>   model, but for the specific object.

Note that you can't call function that takes parameter in Django templates, You should write a template tag.